# Вывести людей, которые подписаны друг на друга

Tags: sql

Есть таблица подписчиков, *user_to* - поле отвечающее за пользователя, на которого подписывались, а *user_from*, кто подписывался. Нужно вывести людей, которые подписаны друг на друга. Буду благодарен за помощь.

**Обновление**

Проблема в том, что реализовать подобный запрос очень сложно, пытался выводить как из двух таблиц, но не получилось. Вот думаю, может, вы можете помочь с данной проблемой.

Comment: @Антон Данилов, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Проблема в том, что реализовать подобный запрос очень сложно, пытался выводить как из двух таблиц, но не получилось. Вот думаю, может, вы можете помочь с данной проблемой.

Comment: @Антон Данилов, покажите, что у вас получилось, пусть даже и неправильно.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Так без дублей будет:

```
select s1.user_from, s1.user_to
from subscr s1 
join subscr s2 on 
      s1.user_from = s2.user_to 
  and s1.user_to = s2.user_from 
  and s1.id<s2.id
```

Comment: ID - идентификатор чего?

Comment: @smackmychi, стандартный суррогатный ключ, разумеется. Подойдет любое поле в принципе, можно и user_from или user_to использовать...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov просто я попробовал код без сравнения - дубли есть. В таблице два поля.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF (table1.user_from>table1.user_to,table1.user_from,table1.user_to) as _from,
IF (table1.user_from<table1.user_to,table1.user_from,table1.user_to) as _to
FROM table1 
JOIN table1 as t1 on table1.user_from=t1.user_to and table1.user_to=t1.user_from
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u1, u2 from (
select case when user_from > user_to then user_from else user_to end u1,
       case when user_from > user_to then user_to else user_from end u2
from subscr
) x group by u1,u2 having count(*) =2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s1.user_from from subscribes s1, subscribes s2
where s1.user_from=s2.user_to
```

Comment: Надо **друг на друга**. Вы вывели людей, которые подписаны **на друга**. Т.е. все записи, а некоторые еще и продублированы (как раз те, кто подписан друг на друга).

Comment: Спасибо всем, днем проверю.